# Generic List not accepting subtype

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, collections

```
public interface IRow {}

public class TableA {
    public static class Row implements IRow {}
}
```

Now I created a list where each element of the list contains a List of `IRow`

```
List<List<IRow>> rowsOfTables = new ArrayList<>();
```

Now I want to insert first element in `rowsOfTables` which is a list holding elements of `TableA.Row`. Since I made a list of supertype/interface, so I can do this. Hence I wrote

```
rowsofTables.add(0, new ArrayList<TableA.Row>());
```

**But I am getting error**

```
Required type: List<IDbRow>
Provided: ArrayList<DbRow>
```

What went wrong ?

**EDIT:**

Fixed by changing to this

```
List<List<?>> rowsOfTables = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: That is because `rowsOfTables` is a `List<List<IRow>>`, so the add method takes a `List<IRow>`, and while `ArrayList<IRow>` is a subtype of that, `ArrayList<Row>` is not. You can probably do `rowsofTables.add(0, new ArrayList<IRow>());`. That will still accept instances of `Row` inside.

Comment: But then even this `List<ArrayList<IRow>> rowsOfTables = new ArrayList<>();`doesn't work

Comment: What error do you get for that?

Comment: `Required Type: ArrayList<IDbRow>, Provided: ArrayList<DbRow>`
https://ibb.co/5TCjMNs

Comment: Yes, just like I wrote, an `ArrayList<DbRow>` is not a subtype of `ArrayList<IDbRow>`, so you cannot give that to the add method. Don't say `new ArrayList<DbRow>()`, use `new ArrayList<IDbRow>()`.